# Mapa em SVG no Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, svg

Não consigo inserir o mapa(link abaixo) no Wordpress.
Quando coloco o código na página, os estados ficam enfileirados conforme anexo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Alguém pode me ajudar?
Tks

Segue código (não postei inteiro no snippet pois o SO limita a pergunta para 30000 caracteres):

Online: http://codepen.io/fabiogoodoy/pen/wgipx

```js
function highlight_map_states(){
  if($(".states_section").length>0){
     $(".states_section .list_states .item .link").hover(function(){
       var a="#state_"+$(this).text().toLowerCase();
       $(a).attr("class","state hover")
     },function(){
       var a="#state_"+$(this).text().toLowerCase();
       $(a).attr("class","state")
     })
  }
};
```

```css
#map {
    display: none;
}

#map .state {
    cursor: pointer;
}

#map .state .shape {
    cursor: pointer;
    -width: 0;
}

#map .state .label_icon_state {
    fill: #fff;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 11px;
    line-height: 12px;
    font-weight: normal;
}

#map .state .label_state {
    display: none;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 16px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

#map .state:hover .label_state,
#map .state.hover .label_state {
    display: block;
}

#map .model-green .state .shape {
    fill: #6cb361;
}

#map .model-green .state .icon_state {
    fill: #10592f;
}

#map .model-green .state .label_icon_state {
    fill: #fff;
}

#map .model-green .state .label_state {
    fill: #666;
}

#map .model-green .state:hover .shape,
#map .model-green .state.hover .shape {
    fill: #2d68b2;
}

#map .model-green .state:hover .icon_state,
#map .model-green .state.hover .icon_state {
    fill: #5a95ce;
}

#map .model-orange .state .shape {
    fill: #fd7132;
}

#map .model-orange .state .icon_state {
    fill: #6cb361;
}

#map .model-orange .state .label_icon_state {
    fill: #fff;
}

#map .model-orange .state .label_state {
    fill: #666;
}

#map .model-orange .state:hover .shape,
#map .model-orange .state.hover .shape {
    fill: #c93f04;
}

#map .model-orange .state:hover .icon_state,
#map .model-orange .state.hover .icon_state {
    fill: #10592f;
}

#map .model-darkgreen .state .shape {
    fill: #366823;
}

#map .model-darkgreen .state .icon_state {
    fill: #2779c6;
}

#map .model-darkgreen .state .label_icon_state {
    fill: #fff;
}

#map .model-darkgreen .state .label_state {
    fill: #666;
}

#map .model-darkgreen .state:hover .shape,
#map .model-darkgreen .state.hover .shape {
    fill: #4a8c31;
}

#map .model-darkgreen .state:hover .icon_state,
#map .model-darkgreen .state.hover .icon_state {
    fill: #5a95ce;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<svg id="map" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="460" height="465" style="display: inline;">
...

</svg>

<br />

Créditos <a href="http://bomnegocio.com" target="_blank">bomnegocio.com</a>
```

Comment: Onde colocaste o CSS? e o JS? tens algum erro na página?

Comment: É provável que o ID `#map` já esteja sendo usando no seu template do wordpress. Tente criar um ID unico para não conflitar com outras regras do CSS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

É provável que o o ID `#map` já esteja sendo usando por outro elemento na sua página e provavelmente já tem regras de estilo adicionados, a melhor alternativa é alterar o ID (lembre-se não só por questão de CSS, mas por questão de HTML, nunca repita os IDs), você pode usar um ID como `#mapa_brasil`.

Outra coisa, evite o `display: inline` para estes tipos de elementos, prefira o `display: inline-block;` ou `display: block;`

Por exemplo:

```
<svg id="mapa_brasil" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="460" height="465" style="display: inline-block;">
...

</svg>
```

e no CSS:

```
#mapa_brasil {
    display: none;
}

#mapa_brasil .state {
    cursor: pointer;
}

#mapa_brasil .state .shape {
    cursor: pointer;
    -width: 0;
}

#mapa_brasil .state .label_icon_state {
...
```

Comment: Obrigado Guilherme!! Eu criei um modelo de página somente com o mapa! Agora deu certo! Se puder me ajudar em mais uma dúvida... gostaria de criar uma div de conteudo para cada estado ao clicar. É possível fazer isso? QUando clicar em um estado aparece uma div e quando clicar em outro, some a anterior... Muito obrigado ;)

Comment: Seja bem-vindo @mdesigner A minha resposta resolveu o seu problema? Se sim marque-a como correta clicando no botão verde abaixo dos pontos da resposta. Sobre a sua outra duvida é melhor você criar uma nova pergunta amigo, aqui não somos um fórum de debate, acho que seria legal se você desse uma olhada fizesse um tour para entender como funciona o StackOverflow: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: Resolveu sim, obrigado e desculpa o incomodo ;)

Comment: @mdesigner não é incomodo algum, estamos todos aqui para aprender, seja bem vindo! :)